# What can i do if Atom doesn't find the .csv file in the folder even if it is there?

Tags: plotly, atom-editor, plotly-python

Please, does anyone know why the file 'data/2018WinterOlympics.csv' seems not to exist in the folder even though actually it is there? I'm struggling to understand why...

```
import plotly.offline as pyo

import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/2018WinterOlympics.csv')

print(df)
```

Comment: check if the working directory of the script is pointing to the correct location, ie the directory which contains the `data` folder. You can use `os.getcwd()` to get the current working directory

Comment: FYI: The current path `data/2018WinterOlympics.csv` is with respect to the directory where the current script is running on your filesystem.